# Transfer ERD between Databases on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've a development database on SQL Server 2008. I want to copy the production database back to my development server to get the latest data for testing. Unfortunately the production database is missing the many ERDs I've created to my development database.
If I just restore a backup, I'll loose my ERDs. Is there any way to save or script the ERDs and transfer them to another database if both have the same schema?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you are using the Database Diagrams feature from within SSMS. I found this tool out at CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15080/Script-SQL-Server-2005-diagrams-to-a-file

I cannot speak to how well it would work for you. I would suggest you use a different tool, such as perhaps Visio, in order to create your ERDs so that they are more portable.

Comment: Thank you. Also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527327/how-do-you-migrate-sql-server-database-diagrams-to-another-database